# gradle: downloading specific file from ivy repository

Tags: java, gradle, ivy

We use an internal ivy repository and are in the process from moving away from ant / ivy and tasking everything in gradle.  I have my ivy repository set up in gradle as so:

```
repositories {
    ivy {
        url "${ivy_repository_url}"
        layout "pattern", {
            ivy "repository/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact].[ext]"
            artifact "repository/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact].[ext]"
            m2compatible = true
        }
        credentials {
            username "${ivy_repository_username}"
            password "${ivy_repository_password}"
        }
    }
}
```

and upon executing a task it resolves as expected, however, in some instances it pulls down everything in the repository if the naming convention doesn't match so I end up with a lot of extra stuff, javadocs.zip, sources.zip and everything else.

To get around this I want to download the specific jar files to a temp folder first and then compile them from local but I have no clue how to tell gradle to download a file that is named differently from the module name.

Example:

> ivyFiles 'net.sourceforge.jtidy:jtidy:r938@jar'

downloads just **jtidy-r938.jar** from the **net.sourceforge.jtidy** repository but something like

> ivyFiles 'com.gargoylesoftware:htmlunit:2.7@jar'

would pull **htmlunit-2.7.jar** but not the file **htmlunit-core-js-2.7.jar**.

If I omit the @jar it reverts to calling the **ivy.xml** file and I am left with all the junk + dependencies which I am trying to avoid.  I have tried the following with no success

```
    ivyFiles ('com.gargoylesoftware:htmlunit:2.7'){
        artifact{
            name = 'htmlunit-core-js'
            type = 'jar'
        }
    }
```

There must be a way to do this.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. This is what I ended up doing

```
ivyFiles ('com.gargoylesoftware:htmlunit:2.7'){
    transitive = false
    artifact {
        name = 'htmlunit-core-js'
        extension = 'jar'
        type = 'jar'
    }
}
```

Now only the **htmlunit-core-js-2.7.jar** file was downloaded

Comment: As a side note: HtmlUnit 2.7 is really outdated. Try to switch to the latest one.

Comment: yea, I know.  Right now I am just trying to mirror what our current ant build does. Once I complete that task I will go through and make sure things are updated.